# Magento Bulk product update

Tags: ee-1.13

Im very new to magento, and i have a site of over 20k products. And i need to update all products of the site, and each product has few different attributes than the other. So how to update all the products at once ?? And a solution with clear steps will be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update mass products

Go to Admin panel > Catalog > **Manage Products**

Click on **select all** link
it select all visible products

then, Top right side in **Action** field select **Update attribute** then press submit button it will show products from then you can change any attribute value it will affect in every products which you select.

Comment: ,that is for common attributes among the products can be mass updated. I have a sceneraio where in i want to edit the uncommon attributes  among the products also.

Comment: please check this link : http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-update-attribute-sets-in-bulk.html

Comment: If your attribute set is different then first select attribute set in attribute set name field then select all visible products and update mass attributes

Comment: @Rajan, thnks for that